# Subtle GOTCHA when displaying a PNG file as a KML overlay to an embedded Google Map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, kml

I have been trying for some time to get a PNG file to overlay on top of an embedded Google Map on a [webpage](http://test.wotus.com/wotus/coverage/). I can get the map to display, but the overlay never appears. I have read dozens of KML related questions here on StackOverflow, and read multiple online tutorials, but the solution is escaping me.

Here is the contents of the KML file which is valid according to this [KML validator](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A//test.wotus.com/static/img/Coverage-Map.kml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<GroundOverlay><name>Coverage-Map.png</name><color>88ffffff</color><Icon>
<href>http://test.wotus.com/static/img/Sequential-Coverage-Map.png</href>
<viewBoundScale>0.75</viewBoundScale></Icon><LatLonBox>
<north> 32.90783</north>
<south> 32.53544</south>
<east>-116.5492</east>
<west>-116.9882</west>
</LatLonBox></GroundOverlay></kml>
```

The KML works in Google Earth (with the `<href>` tag adjusted to point locally), and the PNG is overlaid properly.

Here is the html and javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" href="/static/css/wotus.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link type="text/css" href="/static/js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom/css/south-street/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/img/favicon.ico">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initMap() {
            var mapOpts = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.721635, -116.7687),
                zoom: 11,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
            };

            new google.maps.KmlLayer( "test.wotus.com/static/img/Coverage-Map.kml" ).setMap(
                new google.maps.Map(
                    document.getElementById(
                        'gmap_canvas'
                    ),
                    mapOpts
                )        
            )
        }
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        initMap();
    }
</script>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>WOTUS Coverage</title>
<img src="/media/branding/img/antenna.png" class="rightAnchor" alt=""/>
</head>
<body id="wotusbody" style="background-image:url(/media/branding/img/sunset-2-70per.png)" onload="initialize()">

<header id=page_header>
    <img src="/media/branding/img/WOTUS.png" alt="Wireless of the United States" class="Logo"/>
    <nav>
        <ul id="navbar">
            <li><a href="/wotus/home" class="Tabs">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/wotus/about" class="Tabs">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="/wotus/membership" class="Tabs">Membership Plans</a></li>
            <li><a href="/wotus/coverage" id="onlink" class="Tabs">Coverage Map</a></li>
             <li><a href="/wotus/testimonials" class="Tabs">Testimonials</a></li> 
              <li><a href="/wotus/affiliates" class="Tabs">Affiliates</a></li>  
            <li><a href="/wotus/contact" class="Tabs">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>

<div id="Content"><br/>

    <div style="overflow:hidden;height:500px;width:600px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;padding:0;">
        <div id="gmap_canvas" style="height:500px;width:600px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;padding:0;"></div>
        <style>#gmap_canvas img{max-width:none!important;background:none!important}</style>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Your KML works for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/SO_20151212_GroundOverlay.kml)

Comment: Out of curiosity why is this question getting down voted? Did I do something wrong? The question satisfies the criterion outlined on the StackOverflow tour page: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be rather subtle. The problem was in the javascript. As it turns out, `google.maps.KmlLayer()` is strict with the URL you pass it, so you must include the prefix `http://`. It seems strange that this isn't implicit, so this is a GOTCHA that you need to look out for.

To be clear, I changed:

```
new google.maps.KmlLayer( "test.wotus.com/static/img/Coverage-Map.kml" ).setMap(
    new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById(
            'gmap_canvas'
        ),
        mapOpts
    )
)
```

To:

```
new google.maps.KmlLayer( "http://test.wotus.com/static/img/Coverage-Map.kml" ).setMap(
    new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById(
            'gmap_canvas'
        ),
        mapOpts
    )
)
```

Then it started working.

Answer (score 1):

Your [KML file works as posted on my server](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/SO_20151212_GroundOverlay.kml).

If I use the documented way of loading the KML Layer it works from your server as well:

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var mapOpts = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.721635, -116.7687),
    zoom: 11,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), mapOpts);
  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    map: map,
    url: "http://test.wotus.com/static/img/Coverage-Map.kml"
  })
  google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'status_changed', function() {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = kmlLayer.getStatus();
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
body,
html,
#gmap_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="status"></div>
<div id="gmap_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: The key was that google.maps.KmlLayer() is strict with the URLs that it will accept. My URL did not include the prefix `http://` which is what broke it. After making that simple change it started working.